# run test with p-value equals to NA

Tags: r, nonparametric, runs

I am using `runs.test()` of library `lawstat` in R. I am getting following output

```
x<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
> runs.test(x,alternative="two.sided")

Runs Test - Two sided

data:  x
Standardized Runs Statistic = NaN, p-value = NA
```

What could be the possible reason for `Statistic = NaN, p-value = NA` ? How can this be solved?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the same output. However, the following code should do the job:

```
x <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.8)

R <- length(rle(x)$length) # observed runs
n_1 <- length(x[x == 0])
n_2 <- length(x[x == 1])
R_ <- (2 * n_1 * n_2) / (n_1 + n_2) + 1 # expected runs
s_R <- (2 * n_1 * n_2 * (2 * n_1 * n_2 - n_1 - n_2)) / ( (n_1 + n_2)^2 * (n_1 + n_2 - 1) )

Z <- (R - R_) / s_R # test statitics

# H0:  the sequence was produced in a random manner
# Ha:  the sequence was not produced in a random manner  

p.value <- 2 * pnorm(-abs(Z))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will this work for small sample also? Also, any idea why `runs.test()` is giving p-value equals to NA?

Comment: I applied `RunsTest()` function from package `DescTools` for the example you showed, it's showing p-value equals to 0.3358. Any thought on this?

Comment: I don't know why the p-values are different. Is the test statistics identical? However, for a small-sample runs test, there are tables to determine critical values that depend on values of $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Comment: The normal approximation for the test statistic is Z <- (R - R_) / sqrt(s_R) instead of Z <- (R - R_) / s_R. RunsTest in DescTools is calculating the exact p-value on request (exact=TRUE). lawstat runs.test expects a numerical vector y, as the run lengths are calculated from y as y < median(y), resp. y >= median(y). This will in this case fail.